# Github disable merge

Tags: github, pull-request

Is it possible to disable direct merge to my default branch (develop)? I would like to make sure that everyone has to open a PullRequest, where we can do codeReviews, before the code could be pushed to develop.

I made develop as a protected branch, but I am not sure that's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [About protected branches](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/) does include:

> - Can't have changes merged into it until [required status checks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-required-status-checks) pass
> - Can't have changes merged into it until [required reviews are approved](https://help.github.com/articles/approving-a-pull-request-with-required-reviews)

That would be enough to prevent direct unsupervised merge.